# Ajax requests not working on IE and OPERA

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

For some reason I don't get response while using ajax requests. It doesn't work on Internet exploer and Opera. It works on Firefox and Chrome. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registration").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: str,
            success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I added `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to `.htaccess` file but I still don't get it to work on IE and Opera.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What's debugger and/or console say? And why aren't you handling errors just as you're handling successes?

Comment: Why are you using a full URL? Are you attempting to do a cross-domain request?

Comment: The debugger say nothing. It doesen't work on IE 8 and 9 I added error handling but nothing happes. It alway fires success handling

Comment: `http://foobar.com/ajax.php` cannot be the actual URL. Update the question to have the actual url/path. And also, add a `error` callback with console.log(arguments) in its function body and then post back whatever its output.

Comment: I added error callback but the output console.log is empty

Comment: Is the `submit` handler getting executed at all?

Comment: Yes. As I mention the code above works fine on Google chrome and Firefox.

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly, the `alert(msg);` in the `success` callback fires but the message you see is empty in IE8?

Comment: ok then, can you do a `print_r($_POST);` in your `ajax.php` and see 1) what the data looks like in Firefox 2) what the data looks like in IE8?

Comment: I can't see what print_r($_POST) print becose there is no responce. I added echo 'test' in function which dealing with ajax requests but blank responce

Comment: What does the Net tab of your browsers' developer tools say?

Comment: Now I notice that the headers contain strange symbols

Answer (score 0):

In the past I faced the same issue. What solved it is by putting the .ajax call on a var.

```
var callAjax =   function(){
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php",
        data: str,
        success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
        }
```

};

Also try putting the following outside the jquery Click event. (Global)

```
var str = $(this).serialize();
```

I hope this helps.